# PHPサーバーとHTTPサーバー

Tags: html, http

通信 というか 投稿 アップロードをする際 クライアントから出たデータはどこへいってますか？ HTTPサーバーを介して HTMLサーバー そのあと PHPサーバー で レスポンス でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まずPHPサーバやHTTPサーバやHTMLサーバという理解が間違っています。

一般的なPHPを利用したWebサーバの話をさせていただきますが、

[HTTP](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)とはブラウザとサーバがやり取りするための通信規格（プロコトル）です。
HTTPで通信をしてやり取りを進めます。

次に[PHP](http://www.php.gr.jp/)ですが、様々な場面で利用できるプログラム言語です。

次に[HTML](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperText_Markup_Language)ですが、ブラウザが解析して表示できる、テキストの規格になります。

ブラウザとサーバはHTTPの通信規格でやり取りします。
通信した結果を受け取ってサーバで計算処理を実行するのがPHPです。
そしてブラウザに渡すテキストの種類にHTMLがあります。

これらを包括して一括で管理しているのがWebサーバといわれているものになります。

実際は
HTTP以外にもwebsocketだったりHTTPS/2だったり様々な通信規格が存在し、
PHP以外にもrubyだったりpythonだったり様々なスクリプト言語が存在し、
HTML以外にもJSONだったりCSSだったりXMLだったり様々なテキスト規格が存在します。
それらを取りまとめて、一挙に処理運用できるのがWebサーバソフトウェアになります。

つまりは

WebサーバはHTTP通信でクライアントから受け取ったデータをPHPに流し、PHPは受け取ったデータをもとに処理をしHTMLとして吐き出します。さらにそれをWebサーバが、ブラウザにレスポンスとして返すという処理をしています。

Comment: ありがとうございます けっきょく MacからPHPをつかうにはなにをしたらいいですか？

Comment: それは新しい質問ですので、別で投稿をお願いします